# Split tabular into three same-sized colums plus an additional fixed size column

Tags: tables, columns, width

I want to create a `tabular` in LaTeX that has following layout:

> |-1cm-|-remaining size / 3-|-remaining size / 3-|-remaining size / 3-|

The first column has to be small (like 1 cm). The other three columns should all have the same size. I don't want to hard-code the width of these columns. The width shall be automatically adapted based on the width of the whole table.

I haven't found a solution so far. I think it could work by defining a custom column type with the `array` package but I could not find enough documentation.

Can anyone tell me how to do this and also provide a link or a short explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the width of the table, `tabularx` is your friend here, using `X` columntype.

The first column can be done with `p{1cm}` for example, if left alignment in cells is required.

The `X` columntype will distribute the remaining space equally

I left the vertical lines for demonstration only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{1cm}|*{3}{X|}}
\hline
Foo & Foobar & Foobar & Foobar \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Please note that due to the `\tabcolsep` width, there is an extra spacing of `2\tabcolsep` for each column, if not specified otherwise!

If this is not wanted, use `@{}p{1cm}@{}` instead of `p{1cm}`, for example!

[image]